# Trouble linking entries from two sheets for automatic update

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

How do I have text information from one column (Sheet 1, column C) automatically feed into Sheet 2 column A so that, when Sheet one is updated through the Google form it is linked to, the information then is updated in sheet 2?

[Here is the link.](https://docs.google.com/a/sjcsmo.org/spreadsheets/d/1-1_7eu63J87Mk8haoVBbWK4n6EL-G2W4VfUPzGkEEL8/edit#gid=1913167842)

Comment: The current formula in Sheet2!A1 is `=Sheet1!A2` but there isn't a sheet named Sheet1. There is one named "Form Responses 1" and another named Sheet2.

Comment: Just a note that I got it to copy over and update EXCEPT when the information comes through a Google form. When I manually enter information on sheet one, it comes through on sheet two. When I enter it on sheet one through the Google form, it does not carry over to sheet 2.

Comment: When Google Forms pass a response to a Google spreadsheet, it inserts a new row, so reference to cells (i.e. `='Form Responses 1'!C1` ) are not a good choice. Instead use something like `={'Form Responses1'!C:N}`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried that (and put a space in between Responses and 1 to match the sheet name) and it gave me a #REF1.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I did try that (and put the space between Responses and 1 to match the sheet name), but it just gave a #REF1. I did change the file to allow anyone to edit it if you want to give it a try, as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I really appreciate your help, either way.

Comment: Maybe there extra blank spaces. Anyway, take a look to Sheet3!A1 in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJKBwdrw8Cnp5ygPDT-ivibeW1pWQUuJVd-MWjnVaMU/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Thank you. It seems you got it to work. Can I have access to your file so I can copy and paste the formula you used? When I type it in, it still doesn't work. Since yours was successful, I want to just copy it exactly. Or, if you can just input it to my file on Sheet 2, I've given you permission to edit. Sorry such a headache, I don't know what I'm entering wrong.

Comment: Nevermind. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to put the following formula in cell A1 in Sheet2:
=arrayformula('Form Responses 1'!C2:C)
This will auto update all entries that are made in Column C on the first sheet.
If you dislike the name of your first sheet, you cab just rename it of course!